# Obtain Exchange Domain, User, and Password

Tags: android, authentication, exchange-server

I am developing an application in which I want to use the exchange domain, username, and password of one of the users accounts for authentication.

Selecting and fetching the account object is no problem. The issues arises when I attempt to access any of the confidential information contained within the account. Since my application was not the creating activity, I receive a `SecurityException` complaining about uids.

Google allows for third-party applications to authenticate against their Google account seamlessly with a special confirmation activity upon first access. Is there something like this available which will allow me to access an exchange account's domain, username, and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do this. You will need to have the user enter their credentials manually for your app.

Even when authenticating against a Google account, you do not get access to their password. You just get a token that allows access.